# how to have onchange in collection_select with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I am using jquery on my html page and want to have an onchange event on a collection_select.

If I add `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` then my jquery code does not work.

Basically I have a collection_select as follows:

```
<%=collection_select(:product, 'prod_name', @prods, :id, :prod_name, 
{:prompt => 'Select Product'},{:onchange =>  remote_function(:url => 
{:action => 'volume_or_quant'}, :with => "'id=' + this.value")})%>
```

Then I have a select tag and a text field:

```
<%=select_tag :volume, options_for_select(["", "1/8 lb", "1/4 lb", "Single", 
"Multi 5" ], "N/A") %>
<%= text_field_tag :quantity, "", :size=>"4"%>
```

When an option is selected from the `collection_select` I want to go back to my action and check whether it has volume or unit in the DB. Based on which, the above selectbox/textbox will be enabled.

right now my action looks like:

```
def volume_or_quant
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    puts "Value: " + @product.volume        
end
```

However, when I select something...nothing happens. Right now I do not have default javascripts.

is what I'm trying to do require the default prototype javascript? or can it be done with jquery?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [`remote_function`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html) requires the Prototype libraries be included. It can be done with jQuery, but not with the `remote_function` helper as you are attempting.

**To get jQuery working:**

The problem that occurs when you include the defaults, is that Prototype tries to use `$`, and so does jQuery. You can use jQuery's `noConflict` mode to fix this.

Include the defaults like you attempted to at first, but then follow this advice to get jQuery working again:

You can do a few things, but if you use a local copy of jQuery, add this as the very last line (and include jQuery after the defaults in the `javascript_include_tag` call):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

If you are using the Google CDN, do this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" %>
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.noConflict() </script>
```

Then, make sure all your jQuery code is surrounded with either this (for any code that used to live in `document.ready`:

```
// $ = Prototype
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // $ = jQuery
});

// or shorthand:
jQuery(function($){
    // $ = jQuery
});
```

Or just use this (Creates a private scope where $ = jQuery):

```
// $ = Prototype
(function($){
    // $ = jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I did this with noconflict. but my jquery ui tabs doesnt work. http://pastie.org/824022

Comment: Your document ready call was incorrect, and its important jquery is included *after* the defaults. This is how it should look (or something close): http://pastie.org/824043

Answer (score 0):

By default rails is configured or include to work with prototype not with jquery, the code `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` includes prototype scripts to your html at runtime. There are some plugins for rails like `jRails` to enable jQuery with rails but it doesn't seamlessly integrates with rails yet.